# How to write URI Reference code in RDF?

Tags: rdf, owl

As I know, there are 2 ways to identify a resource in web in RDF. That is URI and URIref. I know how to write a URI. But I can't imagine how to write a URIref.

Please any one can help me to write a URIref to this URI,
http://www.example.org/index.html

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is [URI References](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#dfn-URI-reference) from the RDF 1.0 recommendation in 2004. URIRefs are what RDF 1.0 uses to identify things.

RDF 1.0 was standardised at the same time the IETF were standardising Internationalized Resource Identifiers (IRIs). IRIs (colloquially) are URLs which allow non-ascii characters. An example:

```
IRI: http://www.example.org/Dürst
URI (and IRI): http://www.example.org/D%C3%BCrst
```

As you'll find in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#dfn-URI-reference):

> **Note:** this section anticipates an RFC on Internationalized Resource Identifiers. Implementations may issue warnings concerning the use of RDF URI References that do not conform with [IRI draft] or its successors.

That is: URIRef is what they expected IRIs to be, and implementations were allowed to warn if identifiers didn't conform to the final IRI spec. (As I recall ultimately there was a difference concerning spaces)

RDF 1.1 (2014) [resolves this](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-new/#identifiers):

> Identifiers in RDF 1.1 are now IRIs.

And in answer to you question, since you have no encoded non-ascii characters there's no difference: http://www.example.org/index.html.